# Inverse Fourier Transform and peculiar results

Tags: fourier-analysis, integral-transforms

In order to get Fourier and Inverse Transform of a function $f(x)$ I write the following commands:

As far I can see that Nominator in the quotient of `INF[x]` is zero and the other 2 small quotients sum to 4.... 
What I do not understand is:

1. why Mathematica  prefers to write down in such a complicated way the result..
2. How can I make the result of `INF[x]` looks like the function `f[x]`?

Thanks.

**Some Edit after receiving help.**

```
Element[a, Reals]; 
Element[b, Reals]; 

f[x_] = Piecewise[{{1, a <= x <= b}, {0, \[Placeholder]}}]
(* Piecewise[{{1, a <= x <= b}}, 0] *)

F[s_] = FullSimplify[FourierTransform[f[x], x, s, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}, 
  Assumptions -> Element[s, Reals], Assumptions -> a < b]]
(* Piecewise[{{(I*(E^(I*a*s) - E^(I*b*s)))/s, a < b}}, 0] *)

INF[x_] = FullSimplify[InverseFourierTransform[F[s], s, x, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}, 
  Assumptions -> Element[s, Reals], Assumptions -> Element[a, Reals], 
    Assumptions -> Element[b, Reals], Assumptions -> a < b, Assumptions -> a <= x <= b]]
(* Piecewise[{{(1/4)*(-((I*(Log[1/(a - x)] + Log[I*(a - x)] - 
   Log[a - x] - Log[I/(b - x)] + Log[I*(b - x)] - Log[(I*(b - x)^2)/(a - x)]))/Pi) - 
   2/Sign[a - x] + 2/Sign[b - x]), a < b}}, 0] *)
```

Comment: Please  post Mathematica code so that we can copy it and work on it ourselves.

Comment: @Hugh, sorry but when I copy from notebook and paste it does not look ok...that is why I put a picture. How can I do it right?

Comment: Copy the input cells and paste. Then. select them and click on the curly brackets in the tool bar. Have a go at editing your post.

Comment: Which mathematica version is this? With 12.0 I obtain for `FullSimplify[InverseFourierTransform[FourierTransform[Piecewise[{{1, a < t < b}}, 0], t,w], w, t],a < b]` the result `(Sign[b-t]+Sign[-a+t])/2` which is just the original integrand looking a little bit different.

Comment: As to typesetting of the code, check this post: https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584/1871

Comment: Stand-alone statement like `Element[a, Reals]` tests whether `a` is real. If `a` has not been assigned a value it returns unevaluated since it is neither `True` nor `False`. To declare `a` real this must be added to [`$Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Assumptions.html) or included in an `Assumptions` option. Do not give an option twice in a single command. Second use will override the first. To make assumptions available to all commands that take assumptions, either put them in `Assumptions` or use [`Assuming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming.html).

Comment: @Max1, this is VERSION 12 STUDENT EDITION

Comment: Please format your code https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting

Comment: @dmtri Bob Hanlon's comment is right on spot-on. The problems stem from your spurious `Assumptions`. Evaluating your expressions with ONLY `Assumptions -> a < b` gives `(Sign[b-t]+Sign[-a+t])/2` for the inverse FT. Also note that by convention functions defined by oneself should start with a small letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["`Global`*"]

f[x_] = Piecewise[{{1, a <= x <= b}}]

(* Piecewise[{{1, a <= x <= b}}, 0] *)
```

[`Piecewise`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) defaults to `0` so you do not need to specify a second case.

```
F[s_] = Assuming[{Element[s, Reals], a < b},
  FullSimplify[
   FourierTransform[f[x], x, s, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}]]]

(* (I*(E^(I*a*s) - E^(I*b*s)))/s *)
```

Note that by using [`Assuming`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming.html) the assumptions are available to both [`FourierTransform`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FourierTransform.html) and [`FullSimplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html) since both functions accept an [`Assumptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions.html) option. Although, not important in this case, it is generally a better practice. Similarly, with the following.

```
INF[x_] = Assuming[{Element[s, Reals], a <= x <= b},
  FullSimplify[
   InverseFourierTransform[F[s],
    s, x, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}]]]

(* 1/2 (Sign[b - x] + Sign[-a + x]) *)
```

You can use a custom [`ComplexityFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexityFunction.html) in `FullSimplify` to penalize the use of [`Sign`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sign.html)

```
INF[x_] = Assuming[{Element[s, Reals], a <= x <= b},
  FullSimplify[
   InverseFourierTransform[F[s],
    s, x, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}],
   ComplexityFunction -> (LeafCount[#] + 100*
        Count[#, _Sign, {0, Infinity}] &)]]

(* 1 *)
```

and the constraint of `a <= x <= b` is implied by the assumptions used.

Comment: Excellent help and commentary!!! Thanks a lot!